# PHP SQL display list for each row with same value

Tags: php, sql, list, foreach

I generate a list from the data in my sql database. The problem is that the list prints the "System" name before each remark instead of listing the "Remark" for all rows containing the same "System" name under one .

Code:

```
<?php
require("dbcon.php");
$query = " 
    SELECT 
        id, 
        Date, 
        System,
        Remark
    FROM records
    WHERE Date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'
    ORDER BY Date
    ";
echo "<div id='heading'>EVENT LOG: Last week</div><br />";

$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <ul><?php echo $row["System"]; ?>
    <li><?php echo $row["Remark"]; ?></li></ul>
<?php } ?>
```

This gives me a output like:

```
Systemname1
- Log entry for Systemname 1 (stored under Remark in database)
Systemname1
- Log entry for Systemname 1 
Systemname2
- Log entry for Systemname 2
Systemname2
- Log entry for Systemname 2
```

But what I want is:

```
Systemname1
- Log entry for Systemname 1
- Log entry for Systemname 1

Systemname2
- Log entry for Systemname 2
- Log entry for Systemname 2
```

This can probably be fixed in some way by using foreach(), but I'm not sure how :/

Comment: Is the actual value of remark "Remark1" and "Remark2"?  If so, then you can do it with some string manipulation, but its not your db call or code that is causing your point of pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would choose to use a temp variable to compare with the date, but this question have multiple solutions:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$temp_date = '';
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
  echo "<ul>";  // Start the list only if data exist
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($row["Date"]!=$temp_date) {  // If 'Date' is equal to the previous one, skip
      if($temp_date!='') {  // If it's not the first list 
        echo "</ul><ul>";   // close the previous one and start another
      } 
      echo $row["Date"];
      $temp_date=$row["Date"]; 
    }
    echo "<li>".$row["Remark"]."</li>";
  }
  echo "</ul>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could to all of the sorting and combining in PHP, but here is an option where the databse does the grouping:

```
<?php
require("dbcon.php");
$query = " 
    SELECT 
        id, 
        Date, 
        System,
        GROUP_CONCAT(Remark, SEPARATOR ':::') AS Remark
    FROM records
    WHERE Date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'
    ORDER BY Date
    GROUP BY Date
    ";
echo "<div id='heading'>EVENT LOG: Last week</div><br />";

$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <ul><?php echo $row["Date"]; ?>
    <?php foreach(explode(':::', $row["Remark"]) as $remark) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $remark; ?></li>
    <?php } // END foreach ?>
    </ul>
<?php } // END while ?>
```

Comment: I think you have misspelled _foreach_ clause; maybe you would mean: _foreach(explode(':::',$row["Remark"]) as $remark)_

Comment: Thanks for the catch - that's what happens when you copy-paste with reckless abandon!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is sound :)

I would solve this with code in 2 steps:

First format the sql result into something you can use for rendering:

```
$nestedResult = array();
foreach (mysql_fetch_assoc($result) as $row) {
    if (!isset($nestedResult[$row['Date']])) {
        $nestedResult[$row['Date']] = array();
    }
    $nestedResult[$row['Date']][] = $row['Remark'];
}
```

Then the actual render:

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($nestedResult as $date => $remarks) {
    echo '<li>' . htmlspecialchars($date) . '<ul>';
    foreach ($remarks as $remark) {
        echo '<li>' . htmlspecialchars($remark) . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```